# How to detect whether a process has completed execution

Tags: c#, windows, visual-c++

Here's the scenario:-
 I have two applications - one is in C# and other one is in VC++.
 The one written in C# is the main application and upon a `button click` the VC++ application is made to run inside a `panel` in the C# application. It is running successfully.
But how could I detect whether the VC++ application has completed execution. Although I am able to see that it has completed execution but when I try to use `processname.HasExited` technique to incorporate some other tasks to perform when the VC++ process is complete I am unable to do so. Even
`processname.Exited += new EventHandler(processname_Exited);` don't seem to work.
Can anyway tell me how to solve this problem?

Thanks.

**EDIT#1:**
`processname` is a `System.Diagnostic.Process` object.

Comment: Documentation says "This event can occur only if the value of the `EnableRaisingEvents` property is **true**." Did you remember to set `EnableRaisingEvents` to `true`? P.S., it would help a lot if you mentioned that `processname` is a `System.Diagnostic.Process` object. I had to go searching to figure out what you were talking about.

Comment: @RaymondChen Yes, it is a `System.Diagnostic.Process` object. Sorry, I forgot to mention that. Yes, I have set the value of `EnableRaisingEvents` property to `true`. But still its not working.

Comment: Sounds like that project did not really exit. Check with the task manager: is it still hanging around?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to communicate the 'exiting' of the client application (here VC++ app) to the parent application (here C# app) by sending a Custom Message using PostMessage() API upon WM_QUIT event in the VC++ app. I am not sure though as to how to receive this message in the C# parent app.